# Custom url in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I asked same question [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/107095/custom-url-rewriting)

I am struggling to create custom rewrite rules for wordpress..

This is my url structure

```
http://domain/cityprofile/?city=Sydney
```

where city profile is a page template.

Now i want to make this url as

```
http://domain/Sydney
```

Answer (score 1):

WordPress allows theme and plugin developers to programmatically specify new, custom rewrite rules. The following functions (which are mostly aliases for `WP_Rewrite` methods) can be used to achieve this.

[WordPress rewrite codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API)

Example

Let's assume you are creating a "Nutrition" page for showing nutritional information. This page uses a custom template and takes two variables, food and variety. Instead of passing ugly querystring variables to the page, you can set up a rewrite rule to create some custom pretty URLs. See below...

```
add_rewrite_rule('^nutrition/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?','index.php?page_id=12&food=$matches[1]&variety=$matches[2]','top');
```

This example would match a requested URL like this:

```
example.com/nutrition/milkshakes/strawberry/
```

...and interpret it to actually mean...

```
example.com/index.php?page_id=12&food=milkshake&variety=strawberry
```

NOTE: When using `$matches[]` to retrieve the values of a matched URL, capture group data starts at 1, not 0.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, not tested, can work with some testing and changes.

```
add_action('init', 'add_my_rewrite');
function add_my_rewrite() {
    global $wp_rewrite;
    $wp_rewrite->add_rule('/([^/]+)/','index.php?pagename=cityprofile?city=$matches[1]','top');
    $wp_rewrite->flush_rules(false);  // This should really be done in a plugin activation
}
```